# Graphs with average degree $t$ embed all trees with $t$ vertices

Tags: graph-theory, trees

I want to prove the following:

> A simple graph with average degree at least $t$ contains all trees on $t$ vertices as a subgraph.

I tried proving this by induction. I first showed that if a graph $G$ has average degree at least $t$, then any subgraph $G'$ formed by removing any vertex $v$ from it has average degree at least $t - 1$. Using induction, given a tree $T$ on $t$ vertices, I am able to remove a leaf $l$ from $T$ and embed the remaining tree $T'$ in $G'$. However, this does not guarantee that the parent of $l$ in $G'$ is adjacent to $v$, which hints that I need a more constructive approach.

How can I modify my argument to obtain a solution?

*Remark*: The Erdős–Sós conjecture is very similar to the above statement:

> A simple graph with average degree greater than $t-1$ contains all trees on $t + 1$ vertices as a subgraph.

Comment: This still seems very ambitious. An easier statement to prove is that a simple graph with average degree greater than $2(t-1)$ must contain every $(t+1)$-vertex tree. (This is actually exactly twice the bound of Erdős–Sós, whose corrected statement should read "A simple graph with average degree greater than $t-1$ contains...")

Comment: @MishaLavrov Yes, my attempt to prove this statement is parallel to the statement you mention. Also, isn't "average degree greater than $t - 1$" the same as "average degree at least $t$"? I have seen the conjecture stated in the way you mention, but I rephrased it so it parallels the statement of my question.

Comment: No, the average degree can be a fraction. "Average degree greater than $t-1$" means "at least $\frac12n(t-1) + 1$ edges", while "Average degree at least $t$" means "at least $\frac12 nt$ edges".

Comment: @MishaLavrov Ah, you are right. I'll correct my statement.